# WebAPI OWIN SelfHosting CORS support

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, owin, self-hosting

I am using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi V5.2.3, Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener 3.0.1. Started with the following configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

And the API Controller class is declared using:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class CWebAPIController : ApiController
{
    [Route("API/System/Login"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(string UserID, string Password)
    {
        .... bla bla bla .....
    }
}
```

I am able to invoke the API above using HttpClent on the same computer, but if I trying to invoke the API from another computer (within the same subnet), I got 400 BadRequest response.

I believe this is CORS issue, but may I know how can I solve this. Searching in google yield many results and there are so many version / implementation of WebApi that I don't know which one is correct after trying one whole day.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

EnableCors attribute should work on your API controller. Alternatively you can do one of the followings.

If you want to allow access from any computer then you can use

```
appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Else if you want to have control on which domain/computers to allow then use

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

You'll need to install Microsoft.Owin.Cors package.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring in the Microsoft.Owin.Cors package, and maybe the Microsoft.AspNet.Cors package into your project and initialize CORS in your `Startup` class like this:

```
var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
            {
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                AllowAnyOrigin = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };
            corsPolicy.ExposedHeaders.Add("x-markit-currentpage");
            corsPolicy.ExposedHeaders.Add("x-markit-totalpages");
            corsPolicy.ExposedHeaders.Add("x-markit-totalresults");
            app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider { PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy) }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added cors like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = ConfigureApi();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
     }
    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureApi()
    {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsMessageHandler ());
        return config;
    }
```

CorsMessageHandler is present here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/FetchClimate/blob/master/src/Service/Frontend/CORS/CorsMessageHandler.cs

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For self hosting we need to run the command below in Admin mode.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:<port>/ user=<user id>
```